# How to programmatically trigger HTML button and parse HTML page only after this click in C#?

Tags: c#, android, html, parsing, google-play

I am trying to parse Google play store HTML page in C# .NET core. Unfortunately, Google does not provide APIs to get the mobile application info (such as version, last update ...), while Apple does. This is why I am trying to parse the HTML page and then get the info needed.

However, it seems they published a new version recently, where a user has to press on an arrow button to be able to see the info of the app displayed in a popup.

In order to understand more, consider the example of WhatsApp application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en
In order to get the info of this app (like release date, version ...), the user has to press now on the arrow near "About this app".

Previously, the below code was working perfectly:

```
    var id = "com.whatsapp";
    var language = "en";
    var url = string.Format("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={0}&hl={1}", id, language);
    string result;
    
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
    result = client.DownloadString(url);
    
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(result, "<div class=\"hAyfc\">.*?
<span class=\"htlgb\"><div class=\"IQ1z0d\"><span class=\"htlgb\">(?<content>.*?)
</span></div></span></div>");
     
    objAndroidDetails.updated = matches[0].Groups["content"].Value;
    objAndroidDetails.version = matches[3].Groups["content"].Value;
    ...
```

But now, it's not the case anymore for two reasons:

1. The regular expression is not valid anymore
2. The `client.DownloadString(url)` downloads only the code before triggering the button to display the info, thus I will not be able to extract it bcz it's not available :)) .

So, anybody can help me to solve the issue #2 ? I need somehow to trigger the button in order to be able to match the HTML code needed and extract it.

Thanks

Comment: If you view the source of that link you'll find that all the information you are seeking is buried in there near the bottom.  So I would consider "clicking on the arrow" to be a red herring: you still just need to figure out how to parse that info out of the HTML source.

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks for taking time to read my question. But actually no. Following the download of the page, I was not table to find info like: the version of the app, and the minimum required Android version.

Comment: Ah, yes, evidently just the expanded description of the app is there, but not the vital information you're looking for like version.